# AJAX connection with PHP file by XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**I want to control the answers in my form**

I received this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: $y2,$y3,$y4,$y5,$y6,$y7,$y8,$y9,$y10 in  C:\Server...file.php on line 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17

How to return "n" from PHP file?

HTML:

Comment: What are you trying to do ? what result are you expecting ? and just post a subset of your code to show the problem not all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?y1="+x1+"$y2="+x2+"$y3="+x3+"$y4="+x4+"$y5="+x5+"$y6="+x6+"$y7="+x7+"$y8="+x8+"$y9="+x9+"$y10="+x10,true);
```

You're separating your `GET` parameters with `$` instead of `&`, so it's all ending up as one big parameter `y1`, and hence `y2`-`y10` are undefined.

You need to separate your parameters like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?y1="+x1+"&y2="+x2+"&y3="+x3+"&y4="+x4+"&y5="+x5+"&y6="+x6+"&y7="+x7+"&y8="+x8+"&y9="+x9+"&y10="+x10,true);
```

Comment: I think he meant to type `&` where he typed `$` in the parameters.

Comment: You're right, I caught that after posting,  Updated

Comment: THANKYOU very very very much !!!  I am grateful.